# How to estimate a parameter from a unknown model as follow?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, signal-processing, non-central

Recently I have met a question. I have derived a important indicator in my research on radar signal processing. The indicator $y$ can be calculated by another measured value $x$, and their relationship is:

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}$$

What's most difficult is that the measured value $x$ is derived by a ratio of two signal strengths:
$$
x=\frac{v_1}{v_2}
$$
I am wondering about how the noise and the real signal strengths affect the result $y$. Assume that the two signal have the i.i.d. complex Gaussian noise $(n \sim \text{CN}(0,\sigma^{2}))$ and their real
amplitudes are $q_1$ and $q_2$, then it's obviously that:

$$
v_1=|q_1+n|^{2}={(Re(q_1)+Re(n))^{2}+(Im(q_1)+Im(n))^{2}}=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}({(\frac{\sqrt{2}Re(q_1)}{\sigma}+N(0,1))^{2}+(\frac{\sqrt{2}Im(q_1)}{\sigma}+N(0,1))^{2}})
$$

and so $v_2$

Then $x$ obey double noncentral F distribution, with degrees of freedom $n_1=n_2=2$ and non-centrality parameters $\lambda_1=2(\frac{|q_1|}{\sigma})^{2}, \lambda_2=2(\frac{|q_2|}{\sigma})^{2}$. And the p.d.f. of $x$ is $p(x)$

**Now the question is how do the values of  $q_1,q_2,\sigma$ influence the result? For example, if I get $v_1,v_2,\sigma$ , how do the measured y differ from original y? If I don't know the model at prior, how can I estimate the original y? If the power of noise is known, how can I decide the confidence interval**

$$
\text{measured}\ y\rightarrow y_m=\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{v_1}{v_2}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{v_1}{v_2}}+1}
$$

$$
\text{original}\ y\rightarrow y_o=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{|q_1|^{2}}{|q_2|^{2}}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{|q_1|^{2}}{|q_2|^{2}}}+1}
$$

My intuition is that if $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ is too small or less than 1, the difference would be tremendous.

------------------------------------------------**Separator**-------------------------------------------------

Maybe I am not describing clearly and I would like to add some more.

In this case, I want to get $y_o$, but the key parameters $q_1$ and $q_2$ are mixed with noise. If the noise power $\sigma^{2}$ is small enough, then $y_m$ is surely close to $y_o$.

If $|q_1|$ and $|q_2|$ are fixed, the degree of "close" is only relay on $\sigma$ and can be depicted as
$$
P(\sigma)=\int_0^\infty\,[y_m(x)-y_o]^{2}p(x)\,dx
$$
According to the properties of $p(x)$, if $|q_1|=|q_2|$, then$P(\sigma)=D[y_m(x)]_{p(x)}$

But if $|q_1|\neq|q_2|$, then I think possibly $P(\sigma)\neq D[y_m(x)]_{p(x)}$

Even assuming that they are equal, how to calculate $P(\sigma)$ or get approximate results is still confuesd to me. Numerical solution is easily accessed in matlab, but the analytic solution or its approximation is what I really want to get.

Another case is that $|q_1|$ and $|q_2|$ are also random variables obey a special distribution, and how to analyze $P(\sigma)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "how do the measured y differ from original y"? Are you looking for the distribution of $y$ under the assumption of a specific parametric model for the the $v_i$? Or just its variance? For the latter, the jackknife is a simple method to estimate it *withour* making a parametric assumption.